# ClassLoader: Resources from Callee

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project which contains two sub-projects.

```
parent
 |
 + - - my-api
 |     |
 |      ` - config.properties
 |
 ` - - my-project
       |
        ` - config.properties
```

my-api contains methods which loads resources using

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream(name);
```

my-project calls my-api's method to load config.properties stored in `my-project/src/test/resources`

When I delete `my-api/src/test/resources/config.properties`, the config.properties from my-`project` is loaded correctly. However, if I don't delete it, `my-api/src/test/resources/config.properties` is loaded.

Comment: Why does `my-project` call `my-api` to load resources from `my-project`?

Comment: I guess you are using maven. And also I guess my-api is a dependency of my-project. Try to check your resources configurations for my-api or parent. Maybe via misconfiguration your `test/resources` directory in my-api is treated not as a test resource but just as resource and is packed into my-api jar file

Comment: @Kayaman, I have multiple sub-projects like ````my-project```` all with the same structure but for different purposes. Also for some reason, I had to put all resource validations inside ````my-api````.

Comment: @vitalyros, you guessed right although I am actually using Gradle but the project was originally built from Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're seeing is far from unexpected.

In a normal Java setup, almost all code (apart from core low-level libraries) shares the same ClassLoader, which finds its resources using the CLASSPATH. If more than one classpath entry contains a resource with the same path, then the resource belonging to entry that appears first on the classpath will be returned. From the [URLClassLoader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL%5B%5D,java.lang.ClassLoader)):

> The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and resources after first searching in the specified parent class loader.

In your case, `my-api` must be appearing first on the classpath, so whenever it contains a `config.properties` resource, that will be loaded in preference to the one contained in `my-project`.

You appear to want to load the `config.properties` that resides in the same classpath entry as a particular calling class. This *is* possible, but it requires you to manually determine the root of the classpath entry the calling class is in. It involves quite a lot of code, and it's very difficult to cover all possible class-loading cases (i.e. class folders vs jars vs shaded jars built by downstream projects vs classes loaded over the network vs custom classloaders used downstream vs security managers, etc). So, I'm not going to post details of how to do this here, as I think it's a bad idea. If you really want to go down this route, start by looking at:

```
Foo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

So, what are the alternatives?

You have several options, but my preference would simply be to put the various `config.properties` files in different packages. It's gnerally good practice to have a different base package for each project, so you could do something like this:

```
parent
 |
 + - - my-api
 |     |
 |      ` - - com.my.api
 |            |
 |             ` - config.properties
 |
 ` - - my-project
       |
        ` - - com.my.project
              |
               ` - config.properties
```

Then, you've got 2 choices for how to load these files. If you have a class that you know is in the same package as each properties file, you can load it using that class:

```
void loadConfig(Class<?> sibling) {
    InputStream config = sibling.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass in the package name:

```
void loadConfig(String packageName) {
    String path = "/" + packageName.replace(".", "/") + "/config.properties";
    InputStream config = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    //...
}
```

If you *really* want to determine the package from the callee, you can use the first method along with an ugly hack:

```
void loadConfig() {
    try {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        Class<?> sibling = Class.forName(stackTrace[1].getClassName());
        InputStream config = sibling.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        //...
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Calling class must have been loaded using a different ClassLoader.
        // There's might be some complex code that could be used to recover here,
        // but this should happen rarely, so maybe just propogate Exception
    }
}
```

I don't recommend this last approach.